# What is {p(t):p(2) = 0} in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

In my linear algebra homework, it asks me if the subset of p2 is the subspace of p2, like the question no.2. I know how to verify if it’s the subspace, but I don’t get what it means by {p(t):p(2) = 0}.[image]

Comment: Guessing by $P_2$they mean the space of polynomials in $t$ of degree at most 2.

Comment: That is the set of all polynomials of degree less than or equal two which at zero equal two...

Comment: learn how to type the problem in ajax , this is lazy way of learning math

Answer (score 2):

From the context I would say $\{p(t) \,:\, p(2)=0\}$ are those polynomials that vanish at $t=2$, meaning if you substitute $t=2$ the polynomial evaluates to $0$. You could also say that this set is the set of polynomials which have $t=2$ as a zero/root.

Comment: Does that mean that P is a polynomial function with a degree less than 2, when t =2, the function is 0.

Comment: It depends on the set, you're considering $\{p(t)\,:\,p(2)=0\} \subseteq P_2$ so all the polynomials in this set must have degree $2$. But being in this set they also have a root at $t=2$. Hence, as you said, these are the polynomials of degree $2$ with a root at $t=2$.

Comment: Correction: $P_2$ is the space of polynomials with degree **at most** $2$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, thank you. That is what I had intended to say.

Answer (score -1):

$P_2$ is the set of all polynomial functions of degree at most 2

i.e. $p(t) = a t^2 +b t + c$

$\{p(t):p(2)=0\}$ would be the subset such $p(2)=0$

$p(t) = a (t-2)^2 + b(t-2) = at^2 + (-2a+b)t + 4a-2b$

What is the degree, what is the basis?

Comment: So in my case, {p(t):p(2) = 0}, it would be the subset of P2 such that p(2) = 0?

Comment: Correction: $P_2$ is the space of polynomials with degree **at most** $2$.